# Should questions related to cinnamon desktop environment be answered?

Tags: discussion, scope

Officially Ubuntu supports Unity, KDE, XFCE and LXDE desktop environment. So naturally we can answer relating to them in Ask Ubuntu. But I saw many peoples asking help on cinnamon desktop environment. Since cinnamon is created with Linux mint in mind (not Ubuntu) so isn't the question is out of the scope of Ask Ubuntu? Should we answer that question? If not then this type of question should be closed as soon as it is encountered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The FAQ says it's ontopic:

> Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.

So I would say yes.

Comment: However, given this, if the user says "Using Mint", then the question is offtopic (might include that in your answer, Jorge)