# Is Ubuntu WSL with Linux Mint repos/packages OK for Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently installed Ubuntu on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). After installation, I added the Linux Mint repositories, and installed several packages from them (like `mintinstall` and `cinnamon`). Can I ask questions about this WSL setup on Ask Ubuntu?

I found conflicting ideas for these questions on the Tour page. It would be on-topic under

> running third-party applications on Ubuntu,

but off topic because it may not be

> directly related to Ubuntu, its community, or officially supported derivatives.

By the logo, it's still Ubuntu, but in the code, it's more of a hybrid (uses both Linux distro's repositories).

Comment: A cinnamon PPA or the actual Mint repo's?

Comment: @Fabby I added the actual Mint repos to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, as Zanna [already pointed out](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17935/85695) in her answer, WSL is on topic here as decided by this meta discussion:

[Do we consider "Ubuntu on Windows 10" the same as an official Ubuntu flavour? Do we support it? To what extent?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15229/85695)

In general, adding a non-Ubuntu repository to your system doesn't bar you from asking questions here. If that were so, anyone who had dared add a PPA, for example, wouldn't be able to ask here! The general rule is that if you installed an official Ubuntu flavor, then your system is on topic. That's why we allow questions about [non-Ubuntu kernels](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17049/85695), about desktop environments—[such as cinnamon](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3265/85695)—not used as the default environment of any Ubuntu flavor, about non-default shells and software in general.

However, if your problem is directly related to the mint repositories you added; if, for example, there is a compatibility issue with the packages in the repository and you can't install something *because you have the Mint repos*, then I would say your problem is off topic and you should probably ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://linux.stackexchange.com).

If, on the other hand, yours is a general question about using WSL, then the fact that you happen to have added an extra repository doesn't mean that your question is off topic, no.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this and I mostly agree, but this seems slightly at odds with [that answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17050/527764). Maybe I'm missing something in the difference between repositories and software, but "if there is a compatibility issue with the packages in the repository and you can't install something *because you have the Mint repos*, then I would say your problem is off topic" seems off to me. If someone asked a question here like "I'm using Mint, and I added this Ubuntu repository and now I have a package management issue" I would vote to close that question...

Comment: @Zanna well yes, because they would be using mint, not Ubuntu. I guess I was trying to say that if the problem is on the Mint side of things, say their repo has an issue, then we can't help.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean, if there was an SE site where Mint was on topic but not Ubuntu, I wouldn't expect the question we closed because it was caused by a problem with the Mint repositories to be on-topic there, leaving the asker with nowhere to go to get that repo issue fixed (except U&L, SU, etc!) though I guess that's beside the point.

Comment: @Zanna think of it this way: if the answer is "remove the Mint repos" and the OP is fine with that, let's call it on topic. If the answer requires correcting a problem on the Mint end, then I would say it's off topic.

Comment: It's like US and EU warranty laws, except we actually respect them. As long as what you did didn't cause the issue, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 12):

If running Ubuntu with additional Mint repositories is on topic here, then running WSL ([which is on-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15229/do-we-consider-ubuntu-on-windows-10-the-same-as-an-official-ubuntu-flavour-do)) with additional Mint repositories is on topic here.

I am not aware of a policy here that adding repositories from another distro (usually a bad idea) constitutes off-topicness, and I would expect most users to find such a policy extremely surprising.

[This answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17406/527764) is relevant here.

> I think the important question to ask when deciding if a question is on-topic is **"Is this about Ubuntu?"** but unfortunately people often ask themselves "Is this (also) about something that isn't Ubuntu?" instead. That's the wrong question to ask.

WSL is Ubuntu and questions about running it are on topic.

We should not close questions just because they smell Minty/Windowsy.

Comment: Yes, this. Exactly this.

Comment: Agreed though I partly don't like itUbuntu + something 3rd party has always been ontopic.  But I believe WSL itself should have its own place and questions about the 3rd party can be asked but I would evaluate those on a case by case: it might require expertise we are not expected to have.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, whether on topic or no, I (for one) would certainly hesitate to dive down this particular rabbit hole and would also be unlikely to trust any answers received. Let's think for a moment what's required to do a credible job here.

A) WSL loaded on a Windows platform (Fairly easy to obtain)

B) The desire to risk instability by unnecessarily adding Mint repositories to you installation. (A pretty unlikely choice).

C) The willingness to spend the time answering a question that is unlikely to help anyone other than the slim population that has done exactly what you have done. Quite possibly only you.

I fail to see the benefit of adding Mint repositories to a system that has no GUI and AFAICT [only supports the CLI.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq) I would advise against the course of action and would be unlikely to  personally encourage it by answering questions about it.

**Disclaimer:** The **opinions** expressed here are my own.